# Refer to an Abstract Class type for a factory function, can't create abstract class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to set up a factory function to create child classes of an abstract class.
The factory function should be agnostic of the child class type.

Here's the abstract class :

```
export abstract class AbstractWorkflowTrigger {
    protected params: any = null;
    protected configParams: any = null;
    protected user: any = null;
    protected expectedParams: any = {};

    constructor(params: any = {}, user?: any, configParams: any = {}) {
        this.params = {
            ...configParams,
            ...params
        };
        this.user = user;
        this.checkParams();
    }

    protected checkParams() {
        const missingParams = Object.keys(this.expectedParams).filter(
            (e: any) => this.expectedParams[e].required && !Object.keys(this.params).includes(e)
        );
        if (missingParams.length > 0) {
            throw Error(`Missing required param(s): ${missingParams.join(', ')}`);
        }
        for (const param in this.params) {
            if (this.params.hasOwnProperty(param)) {
                console.log(this.expectedParams);
                if (!this.expectedParams.hasOwnProperty(param)) {
                    throw Error(`Unknown param '${param}'`);
                }
                if (typeof this.params[param] !== this.expectedParams[param].type) {
                    throw Error(
                        `Wrong type for param '${param}', expected '${
                            this.expectedParams[param].type
                        }', got '${typeof this.params[param]}' instead`
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract do(task: ITask): Promise<void>;
}
```

An example of child class:

```
class AddCommentWorkflowTrigger extends AbstractWorkflowTrigger {
    expectedParams = {
        comment: {
            required: false,
            type: 'string'
        },
        text: {
            required: true,
            type: 'string'
        }
    }
    public async do(task: ITask): Promise<void> {
        if (task.comments.length > 0) {
            task.comments += "\n";
        }
        if (this.params.comment) {
            task.comments += `${this.params.text} - ${this.params.comment}`  
        } else {
            task.comments += `${this.params.text}`;
        }

    }
}
```

I need a factory function to run the `checkParams()` function, as the `expectedParams` member isn't set to the child class value on the constructor of the abstract class, and I don't really want to run the same constructor() function on each child class in order to stay DRY.

The factory function I have so far:

```
export function workflowTriggerFactory(c: any, ...params: any[]): AbstractWorkflowTrigger {
    const built = new c(params);
    c.checkParams();
    return built;
}

export const WorkflowTriggers = {
    assign: AssignWorkflowTrigger,
    setOwnershipToUser: SetOwnershipToUserWorkflowTrigger,
    unsetOwnership: UnsetOwnershipWorkflowTrigger,
    addComment: AddCommentWorkflowTrigger
};
```

Is supposed to be called like this:

```
   await this.executeTriggersOnTask(category.actions[action].triggers, task, params, user);
```

Previous usage (couldn't get the expectedParams to the child class value):

```
   const action: AbstractWorkflowTrigger = new (WorkflowTriggers as any)[trigger](params, user);
```

I am unsure about how to type the `c` param for the factory function, as I would like to stay type safe but using `AbstractWorflowTrigger` won't let me run `new` over it.

What signature should I go for?
Maybe you will see a better way to have efficient code while having `expectedParams` on the correct value when the Abstract class runs `checkParams()`?

Comment: I might have a solution for you but I need to fool around in the TS playground for a bit first. As for typing the `c` parameter could you do something like `type Ctr<T> = new () => T`?

Comment: Could you also explain the difference between `params`, `configParams`, and `expectedParams` in what you're trying to achieve

Comment: params are parameters coming from an HTTP POST request, configParams are parameters set up in YAML file and expectedParams are the params expected for the TriggerAction (required or not). What is that `type Ctr<T> = new () => T` doing?

Comment: It's defining a type alias where given a generic T the type can instantiate a T using the new keyword. Try putting this at the top of a file, create a named empty class, create a variable with this type, and finally assign that variable to the named empty class. You should see that the type captures the ability to instantiate that class.

Comment: Is the deriving class or the generic class supposed to be defining the expected params?

Comment: The deriving class is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're trying to do but I think this should work for your needs or be close enough that you can modify it to fit your use case. There's not a strong reason why I pulled out the `checkParams` function other than my own coding preferences, in my opinion having a functional core is preferred. The secret sauce here is that TS lets you return class definitions from within a function. I leverage that to define class that can be instantiated by another piece of code later. This class checks the parameters against what is supplied by the factory using some closure magic.

```js
type Param = { required: boolean, type: string }
type Params = Record<string, Param>

function checkParams<T extends Object>(schema: Params, obj: T) {
    let schemaKeys = Object.keys(schema);
    let requiredSchemaKeys = schemaKeys.filter(key => schema[key].required);
    let objKeys = Object.keys(obj);
    let missingRequiredSchemaKeys = requiredSchemaKeys.filter(key => !objKeys.includes(key))
    let missingObjKeys = objKeys.filter(key => !schemaKeys.includes(key))

    if(missingRequiredSchemaKeys.length > 0) {
        throw Error(`Missing required param(s): ${missingRequiredSchemaKeys.join(', ')}`);
    }
    
    if(missingObjKeys.length > 0) {
        throw Error(`Unknown param(s): ${missingObjKeys.join(', ')}`);
    }
    
    for(let key of schemaKeys) {
        let param = schema[key];
        let value = (obj as any)[key];
        let actualType = typeof value;
        let expectedType = param.type;
        if(actualType !== expectedType) {
            throw Error(`Wrong type for param '${param}', expected '${expectedType}', got '${actualType}' instead`);
        }
    }
}

interface ITask {}

interface IWorkflow {
    expectedParams: Params
    params: Record<string, any>
    user: any
    run(task: ITask): Promise<void>
}

abstract class AbstractWorkflow implements IWorkflow {
    expectedParams: Params
    params: Record<string, any>
    user: any

    constructor(params: Record<string, any>, expectedParams: Params, user: any) {
        checkParams(expectedParams, params)
        this.params = params;
        this.expectedParams = expectedParams;
        this.user = user;
    }

    abstract run(task: ITask): Promise<void>
}

class WorkflowFactory {
    protected expectedParams: Params;

    constructor(expectedParams: Params = {}) {
        this.expectedParams = expectedParams;
    }

    workflow(name: string, runner: (this: IWorkflow, task: ITask) => Promise<void>): new (params: Record<string, any>, user: any) => IWorkflow {
        let self = this
        let clazz = class extends AbstractWorkflow {
            constructor(params: Record<string, any>, user: any) {
                super(params, self.expectedParams, user)
            }

            run(task: ITask): Promise<void> {
                return runner.call(this, task)
            }
        }
        
        Object.defineProperty(clazz, 'name', {
            writable: false,
            value: name
        })
        return clazz
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but I'm afraid I don't understand everything that's been done here.
Is there a way to use that <T> template in a simpler way to make my code work ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem well enough to propose anything else. You could slim down the code in your question and isolate what it is you want or you could alternatively give me a https://typescript.org/play link that has an obvious error that I could then fix and send back